# pagecontainerbeforeshow - jQuery Mobile 1.4

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

In jQuery Mobile 1.4.x, the way page events are handled were changed. As opposed to binding the `data-role="page"` `div` to specific page events like `pagebeforeshow`, etc. - we now bind to a delegate handler. E.g.

**Old:**

```
$('#pgOne').on('pagecontainerbeforeshow', function (e) {
    alert('I am now on page one!');
});

$('#pgTwo').on('pagecontainerbeforeshow', function (e) {
    alert('I am now on page two!');
});
```

**New:**

```
$(':mobile-pagecontainer').on('pagecontainerbeforeshow', function (e) {
    alert('...');
});
```

The new way is awful, since I have no way of defining the event for each page - e.g. I can no longer define the events for `#pgOne` vs. `#pgTwo`.

How do I achieve the behaviour in the old example, using the new methodology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the API Docs:  http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-beforeshow

You can use ui.toPage to get the page being shown:

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "pagecontainerbeforeshow", function( event, ui ) {
    alert(ui.toPage.prop("id"));
} );
```